# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle a+ib\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/\langle a^2+b^2\rangle$ where $a, b$ are relatively prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

My attempt : 
Define a map $f$ from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Z}[i]/\langle a+ib\rangle$
  by $f(n) = n+\langle a+ib\rangle$.

Then I have shown that $f$  is ring homomorphism and kernel is $\langle a^2+b^2\rangle$.

For subjectivity let p+iq $\in \mathbb{Z}[i]$. Now a+ib $\in \langle a+ib \rangle$ implies ib+$\langle a+ib \rangle$ = -a+$\langle a+ib \rangle$. Similarly i(a+ib) $\in \langle a+ib \rangle$ implies ia+$\langle a+ib \rangle$ = b+ $\langle a+ib \rangle$.

Now a and b are relatively prime implies there exist integers u, v such that au+bv=1.

Now p+iq +$\langle a+ib \rangle$ = p+iq(au+bv) +$\langle a+ib \rangle$ =p+iqau+iqbv+$\langle a+ib \rangle$ =p+bqu-aqv+$\langle a+ib \rangle$ =$f(p+bqu-aqv) $. Hence f is surjective.

Is proof of subjectivity correct?

Comment: Can you show that if $0\le m<n<a^2+b^2$ then $f(m)\ne f(n)$?

Comment: One way of proving surjectivity is to verify that that quotient ring of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ has exactly $a^2+b^2$ elements. This has been studied on our site also. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/76912/11619) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52537/11619).

Comment: +1 for showing your work. I needed to vote to close as a duplicate as this is a recurring exercise (because it is a nice exercise! See the visual answer in one of the linked threads.). I have a related dupehammer privilege so my vote took effect immediately.