# Isomorphism of the fields $\mathbb{Z}[i]/p\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, ring-isomorphism

I am given the task of showing that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/p\mathbb{Z}[i]\cong\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ for $p\equiv3$ mod $4$ prime.

I understand that there exists only one field of order $p^2$ up to isomorphism, so I thought it'd be a good idea to instead show that $$\mathbb{Z}[i]/p\mathbb{Z}[i]\cong\mathbb{F}_{p}[X]/(X^2+1).$$ As far as I'm aware this would ascertain that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/p\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has order $p^2$ and so the result would follow. To do this I used the map $$\psi:\mathbb{Z}[i]/p\mathbb{Z}[i]\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_{p}[X]/(X^2+1)$$ $$a+bi\mapsto a+bX$$

After some quick calculations it's clear that this is a surjective homomorphism of the given fields, and injectivity can be checked by showing that the kernel of this map is generated by $0$. The map is an isomorphism and so the required result follows.

The fact that I haven't used that $p\equiv3$ mod $4$ leads me to think that there is a mistake in my workings. My only idea is that $X^2+1$ is only irreducible (and so $\mathbb{F}_{p}[X]/(X^2+1)$ is only a field) when $p\equiv3$ mod $4$, though this isn't a statement I'm confident in.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76912/why-does-the-ideal-abi-have-index-a2b2-in-mathbbzi?noredirect=1&lq=1) for a solution, with $a+bi=p$, i.e., $b=0$.

Comment: First Supplement to Quadratic Reciprocity: For odd primes $p$, the congruence ${\displaystyle x^{2}\equiv -1{\bmod {p}}} $ is solvable if and only if $\displaystyle p
\equiv 1 \bmod 4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is fine.  According to the first supplement to quadratic reciprocity, for odd primes $p$, the congruence $x^2\equiv-1\bmod p$ has solutions if and only if $p\equiv1\bmod4$.