# $R = \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$, what is the quickest route to write the elements of $R/(2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

My intuition tells me that:

$R/(2) = \{a + b\sqrt{-3} : a, b \in \{0, 1\}\}$ is a complete set of coset representatives, but not sure how to prove that.

<strike>Would it suffice to show that $R/(2) \approx \Bbb{Z}/(2) \oplus \Bbb{Z}/(2)$?</strike>

Would it be best to use the opposite construction $R = \Bbb{Z}[X] /(X^2 + 3)$?

Comment: Yes, use that $R = \Bbb{Z}[X] /(X^2 + 3)$ and conclude $R/(2)\simeq \Bbb{Z/(2)}[X] /((X+1)^2)$. Btw, this isn't isomorphic to the direct sum you mentioned.

Comment: @user26857 how did you get $(X+1)^2$?

Comment: Since $3=1$ and $X^2+1=(X+1)^2$.

Comment: @user26857 is $\Bbb{Z}[X]/(X^2 + 3)$ represented by $\{ a X + b : a,b \in \Bbb{Z}\}$?

Comment: I'd say so.${}$

Comment: Reason as in the first line of the proof I [gave here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2374203/242) and see [also here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1314975/242)