# Determining number of cosets in a quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

It was proved in class that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/<a+bi>$ has $a^2+b^2$ elements which I did not understand.

$a+bi$ is equivalent to $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/<a+bi>$. $a+bi=0 \implies i=\frac{-a}{b}\implies a^2+b^2=0$. Which means that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/<a+bi>$ has $a^2+b^2$ distinct cosets. So I didn't understand the last step, why does that imply $a^2+b^2$ cosets? Thanks and appreciate a hint.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/373163/242) for a *complete* simple proof.

Comment: A short, geometric answer is that the number of lattice points inside the fundamental domain of a sublattice is the area of that fundamental domain, which in this case is $c^2=a^2+b^2$, by the pythagorean theorem.

Comment: That is neat, thanks.

Comment: @manifolded See also [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/23358/242)