# $a+bi\mid n \implies a^2 + b^2\mid n$ if $(a,b)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, divisibility, gaussian-integers

This seems very simple, but I have not been able to come up with an answer to it.

> Suppose $a+bi \mid n$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $(a,b)=1$. Prove that $a^2 + b^2 \mid n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

My attempt was: $a+bi \mid n \implies \overline{a+bi}\mid n$ (otherwise $n$ is not an integer), and if we have that $(a+bi,a-bi)=1$ (or a unit) in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then by unique factorization this implies that $(a+bi)(a-bi)\mid n$. However, I found it difficult to prove $(a,b)=1$ in $\mathbb{Z} \implies$ $(a+bi,a-bi)=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Does anyone have a nice solution to this? Any solution is welcome.

For additional context, this question came up as I was trying to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a-ib) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(a^{2}+b^{2})\mathbb{Z}$ when $a,b$ are coprime in the integers. A way of doing this using natural injections is given in [Quotient ring of Gaussian integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23358/quotient-ring-of-gaussian-integers), where there are many very good answers. One way is to use the first isomorphism theorem with the canonical map $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z[i]/(a - i b)$, and I need to prove that the kernel of that map is $\langle a^2+b^2 \rangle$. In every answer I saw on this, the solution skips over that step, making me suspect that there's something very simple I'm missing.

Comment: Well, taking norms immediately shows that $a^2+b^2\mid n^2$. (I'm not sure about the stronger statement $a^2+b^2\mid n$.) You can also think about using the Euclidean algorithm on $(a+bi,a-bi)$ perhaps.

Comment: @YiFan Thanks for the comment, yes, I noticed that as well. But I was uncertain how to proceed from there. But the fact that the isomorphism ("additional context" part) holds is proof that indeed $a^2+b^2 | n$, so I think it holds. I was trying to prove the above in order to prove the isomorphism, so I still don't have a proof.

Comment: @metamorphy Thank you for the hint. I tried something like that where $d$ was a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, but I didn't get anywhere, and I tried it in a different approach. Could you be a bit more specific with your hint? (I'm rather very slow with hints....)

Comment: Hint: *rationalize* the denominator of $\,n/(a+bi).\,$ See [our answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/373163/242) in the linked dupe for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some $c,\,d\in\Bbb Z$ satisfy $(a+bi)(c+di)=n$. For this to be real, $c+di=k(a-bi)$ for some $k\in\Bbb Q$, whence $k(a^2+b^2)=n$. Now we just need $k\in\Bbb Z$, which follows from $(a,\,b)=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you help me understand why $(a,b)=1$ implies $k\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Albert $k=c/a=d/b$, so $bc=ad$. Since $a$ is coprime to $b$ yet divides $bc$, $a|c$, so $k\in\Bbb Z$.