# Elementary Proof is isomorphism between quotient groups of gaussian integers

Tags: abstract-algebra

In order to show that, for example $Z[i]/(2-i)\cong Z/5Z$ or $Z[i]/(4-i)\cong Z/17Z$, is there any solution that explicitly constructs a homomorphism between the two sets, establishes that it is a homomorphism, and then shows that it is both injective and surjective? The related threads on this sight invoke the first isomorphism theorem, so I was wondering if there is anything more elementary.

Can you do the same to prove the more general result that $Z[i]/(a+bi)\cong Z/N(a+bi)Z$ for $(a,b)=1$?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373073/quotient-rings-of-gaussian-integers.

Comment: See this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385013/what-is-the-quotient-mathbb-z-sqrt3-12-sqrt3/385023#385023

Comment: @lhf The first link uses the isomorphism theorem.. is it necessary to find the kernel?

Comment: The computation of the kernel is feasible.  If you have $n (mod\ a+bi)$ with $a,b$ coprime, then $a+bi|n$ precisely when $n=a^2+b^2,$ for the only Gaussian integers $z$ such that $z(a+bi)$ is an integer are rational multiples of $a-bi$, and since $(a,b)=1$ they are all integral multiples of $a-bi$.