# Determine whether $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+1)$ is an ID, UFD, PID, field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to determine whether $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+1)$ is an ID, UFD, PID, field.

My progress so far: I know that field $\Rightarrow$ PID $\Rightarrow$ UFD $\Rightarrow$ ID. The units of the ring are $\pm 1$, $\pm X$ (by considering $(aX+b)(cX+d)=1$, equating coefficients and using that $X^2 + 1 = 0$). So the ring isn't a field as not every element is a unit.

How should I continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that the ring is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ of Gaussian integers.
Then find out here at MSE what is known about this ring (quite a lot is known and has been answered. To give an example, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600424/prove-that-the-gaussian-integers-ring-is-a-euclidean-domain)). In fact, it is norm Euclidean, hence a PID and hence an UFD. You have shown that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is not a field, and as a subring of $\mathbb{C}$ it is clearly a domain, i.e., ID.

Comment: "Then find out here at MSE what is known about this ring." =D