# Prove that in $\Bbb{Z}$, $\forall a,b\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that $a = bq +r$, we can find $r$ such that $-\frac{1}{2}b \leq r \leq \frac{1}{2}b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In $\Bbb{Z}$, we know that for all $a, b \in \Bbb{Z}$, we can express $a = bq + r$ such that $|r| < |b|$. However, I read from this post

[Prove that the Gaussian Integer's ring is a Euclidean domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600424/prove-that-the-gaussian-integers-ring-is-a-euclidean-domain)

that it is also true that we can find r such that $-\frac{1}{2}b \leq r \leq \frac{1}{2}b$. I am able to prove this by considering four case, when $r$ is less than half of $b$,more than half of $b$, $r$ is half of $2b$ or $r$ is twice of $2b$. However, i find this proof to be very ugly. Can someone provide me with a more elegant proof of this fact. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Among any $b$ consecutive integers you can find a multiple of $b$ (because there's only $b$ different possible remainders). $(a- \lfloor \frac{b}{2} \rfloor), ..., (a+ \lfloor \frac{b}{2} \rfloor) $ is a list of at least $b$ consecutive integers, so there is a number $qb$ among them. Then $r=a-qb$ will suffice.

Comment: i don't understand your last part, "... so there is a number qb among them. Then r=a−qb will suffice." Can you explain more? Thanks

Comment: By "there is a number $qb$ among them" I meant that there is a multiple of $b$ among them (which I've denoted by $qb, q \in \mathbb{Z}$). Then for $r=a-qb$ it holds that $a=qb+r$ and since $qb$ was close enough to $a$, $-\frac{1}{2}b \leq r \leq \frac{1}{2}b$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the division algorithm to  y = a + floor(b/2) to get y = qb + r'.

Set r = r' - floor(b/2).