# How to describe a systematic way to do division with remainder in $Z[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, gaussian-integers

link 1:
https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2014/math/algebra2/sol3

link 2:

http://www.math.washington.edu/~sullivan/4036s_wi13.pdf

I have found 2 solutions, the second one convinced me. But so far I cannot formally prove that the method given in the first link gives a reminder with its size function less then the size function of the divisor. And I think maybe there exist Gaussian integers $a+bi$, $c+di$, such that using the division algorithm in link 1 to divide $c+di$ by $a+bi$ gives a remainder whose size function value is greater than the size function value of $a+bi$.

Is it possible? If it is possible, could someone find such $a+bi$ and $c+di$?If the method in link 1 also allows us to always get a remainder with size function value less then the divisor, could someone formally prove that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, because $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a Euclidean ring. For a proof see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600424/prove-that-the-gaussian-integers-ring-is-a-euclidean-domain) on this site. It is very similar to your links, but might give you more information. The second link does the full computation for a given example. What problem do you see there? The remainder must get smaller, as is proven at the duplicate above.

Comment: Thank you! But may I ask how to prove the existence of r with its norm less then 1/2 N(b)?