# $2=(1+i)(1-i)$ what does that imply in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]\ $ $\ \ 2|(1+i)(1-i)=2$ but $2\nmid (1\pm i)$

So is $2$ not prime (or is it prime but irreducible) in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ or is $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ not a unique factorization domain?

Comment: Yes, $2$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, as you have just demonstrated. No, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ *IS* a unique factorization domain, in fact it is a Euclidean domain.

Comment: But it is irreducible right?

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt No, it is not irreducible, because neither $i+1$ nor $1-i=-i(1+i)$ are units.

Comment: Of course $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a UFD, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600424/prove-that-the-gaussian-integers-ring-is-a-euclidean-domain).