# Prove that $\Bbb{Z}[i]/I$ is finite where I is an ideal of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Show that for any nontrivial ideal $I$ of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$, $\Bbb{Z}[i]/I$ is finite.

$\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID, so $I=\langle{a+ib\rangle}$. Now $\Bbb{Z}[i]/I$ has elements of the form $c+id+\langle{a+ib}\rangle$. Now I have a vague idea how it'll be finite: $a+ib=0$ gives $a^2=-b^2$. So..?

Comment: Think that both $a^2+b^2$ and $i(a^2+b^2)$ will be in $I$. Does that make you see the light?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes. So we'll view the $c$ and $d$ modulo $a^2+b^2$

Comment: Correct, zed! ${}$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23358/quotient-ring-of-gaussian-integers

Answer (score 2):

Let $a+ib \in I \setminus \{0\}$. Then $n:=a^2+b^2$ is a positive integer contained in $I$. It follows that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/I$ is a quotient of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\,[x]/(x^2+1)$, which is of course finite.

Comment: I don't know torsion groups, will look them up.

Comment: I've replaced it with a direct argument.