# Is $A=\Bbb Z[i] /(3+i)$ finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain, gaussian-integers

The quotient ring contains the classes of the remainders of divisions $\frac {a+ib}{3+i},$ $a,b\in \Bbb Z $. That ratio is equal to $\frac {3a+b}{10} +i\frac {3b-a}{10} $. Does this tell me what the classes look like?

Anyway, the given answer says that every class contains a representative with norm smaller than $10$, and since the elements of $\Bbb Z[i]$ that have such a norm are finitely many, this shows that $A $ is finite. How do we deduce the first statement?

---

Also, I had tried a more convoluted approach: $ \Bbb Z[i] $ is a PID so $3+i$ not being irreducible implies $(3+i) $ not being maximal, and thus $A $ is not a field. In turn, this means that $A$ is not a finite integral domain (since it obviously has more than $1$ element). I guess $A $ is finite, so what is an example of a zero-divisor of it?

Comment: **Hint** $\  w = 3+i\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, N(w) = w\bar w = 10\equiv 0\ \ $

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242142/prove-that-bbbzi-i-is-finite-where-i-is-an-ideal-of-bbbzi?rq=1

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you but I'm sorrry, I wasn't able to proceed

Comment: $$3+i = (1-i) \cdot (1+2i)$$

Comment: @Richard I elaborated with a sketched proof in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

In this case the ideal $(3+i)$ is not so complicated hence it’s relatively easy to find a combination such as $10=(3+i)(3-i)$. But this might not always be the case; at times when its difficult to guess such a combination you can always work with the ideals in the following manner.

\begin{align}
\Bbb Z[i]/(3+i) &\cong \frac{\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2+1)}{(3+x)} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \text{Since} \; \Bbb Z[i]\cong\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2+1)\\
&=\frac{\Bbb Z[x]}{(x^2+1,3+x)}\\
&\cong\frac{\Bbb Z[x]/(3+x)}{(x^2+1,3+x)/(3+x)} \;\;\;\;\;\;\; [\text{by Third Isomorphism Theorem for rings}]\\
&
\end{align}

Now $\Bbb Z[x]/(3+x)\cong\Bbb Z$ by First Isomorphism Theorem for rings.

Also in the quotient $(x^2+1,3+x)/(3+x)$,

$3+x=0$

and $x^2+1=(3+x)(-3+x)+10\implies x^2+1=10$

Hence $(x^2+1,3+x)/(3+x)=10\Bbb Z$

Finally, $$\Bbb Z[i]/(3+i)= \Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z$$

So the quotient in fact has exactly $10$ elements.

Comment: Thank you, this approach is really interesting. However these theorems are studied in the subsequent course; I'll definitely come back at this.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1214702/242) for teh quotient reciprocity from the 3rd Isomorphism Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

$h\!: \Bbb Z \to \overbrace{\Bbb Z[i]/(3\!+\!i)}^{\textstyle A}\color{#0a0}{ \ {\rm is\ surjective\  (onto)}}\,$ by $\!\bmod\, 3\!+\!i\!:\ \, i\equiv -3\,\Rightarrow\, a\!+\!bi\equiv a\!-\!3b\in\Bbb Z$

$\color{#c00}{I := \ker h = 10\,\Bbb Z}\ $ follows immediately by means of $\,\rm\color{#48f}{rationalizing}\,$ a denominator

$$ n\in I\iff 3\!+\!i\mid n\ \, {\rm in}\, \ \Bbb Z[i]\iff \dfrac{n}{3\!+\!i}\in \Bbb Z[i]\!\!\color{#48f}{\overset{\large \rm\ rat}\iff}\! \dfrac{3n\!-\!\color{#c00}ni}{\color{#c00}{10}}\in\Bbb Z[i]\iff \color{#c00}{10\mid n}\ $$

Thus $\, \color{#0a0}{A = {\rm Im}\ h} \,\cong\, \Bbb Z/\color{#c00}{\ker h} \,=\, \Bbb Z/\color{#c00}{10\,\Bbb Z}\ $ by the First Isomorphism Theorem.

---

**Remark** $ $ By above we obtain an isomorphism $\ f(a+bi) = a-3b\,\bmod 10,\,$ which could also be directly verified. It is instructive to examine why it is multiplicative

$$\begin{align} f((a+bi)(c+di)) &= f(a+bi)f(c+di)\\[.3em]
{\rm by}\ \ \ ac\color{#c00}{-1}bd-3(ad+bc) &\equiv (a\color{#c00}{-3}b)(c\color{#c00}{-3}d)\pmod{\!10}\\[.3em]
{\rm by}\ \ \ \color{#c00}{{-}1} &\equiv \color{#c00}{(-3)^2}\!\!\pmod{\!10}
\end{align}$$

The isomorphism can be viewed as arising from a generalization of the division algorithm, namely reduction modulo a Hermite normal form basis, e.g. see [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2135345/242)

Comment: For finiteness we need only $\,\ker h\supseteq (n)\,$ for some integer $\,n\neq 0,\,$ which is clear since the kernel contains the norm $\,n = w\bar w$ of $w = 3+i\ \ $

Comment: More generally see [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/373163/242)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Zi}{\Bbb Z[i]}$
As Bill Dubuque points out, $10=(3+i)(3-i)$. The size of $A$ is the number
of equivalence classes of $\Zi$ under the relation $\alpha\sim \beta$
whenever $\alpha-\beta$ is a multiple of $3+i$. But if $\alpha-\beta$
is a multiple of $10$ then $\alpha-\beta$ is a multiple of $3+i$. If we
could show that $\Zi$ had finitely many equivalence classes under the
relation $\alpha\sim'\beta$ whenever $\alpha-\beta$ is a multiple of $10$
then we would be in business.

For the question's given answer, this follows from the fact that
if we round $\alpha/(3+i)$ to the nearest element $\gamma$ of $\Zi$
then $\alpha\sim\alpha-(3+i)\gamma$ and the norm of $\alpha-(3+i)\gamma$
is $<10$.

Comment: Thanks for covering both approaches. For the first one: I let $\alpha=a+ib $ and $\beta=x+iy $ and find that $\alpha\sim'\beta $ iff $a\sim' x $ and $b\sim' y $. From this I concluded that the cardinality of the set of equivalence classes under $\sim'$ is the same as $\lvert\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z\rvert^2=10^2$, and thus $A $ is finite, is it correct?   For the second approach: how is the norm of $\alpha -(3+i)\gamma $ smaller than $10$? As above I tried writing $\alpha $ and $\gamma $ in algebraic notation but I ended up with a mess...

Comment: Any hint for me? :(