# Modular inverse of Gaussian Integers

Tags: finite-fields, gcd-and-lcm, gaussian-integers

Let $f_0$ and $f_1$ be Gaussian Integers such that $f_0 = a + i$ and $f_1 = b + i$. How can I compute $f_0^{-1} mod f_1$ and $f_1^{-1} mod f_0$?

I've been trying to apply the Extended Euclidean algorithm, as I would do in other Finite Field contexts, but the result never converges. Am I missing something?

Comment: Don't you mean Gaussian Integers, instead of Galois Integers?

Comment: The ring of Gaussian integers is [Euclidean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain), so the algorithm converges all right. May be you did something wrong? May be you didn't always get to the smallest remainder? Can you show us an exampe, where you couldn't make the calculation converge!

Comment: A thought: May be your experiments went South because if both $a$ and $b$ are odd, then $a+i$ and $b+i$ share the common factor $1+i$? In that case there are no modular inverses because those exist only when there are no common divisors.

Comment: @Stefan4024 yes I do! Thank you =)

Answer (score 2):

Because you are strangely reluctant to give examples of your calculations I can only guess.

**Possibility 1.** When $a$ and $b$ are both odd the computation will automatically fail because in this case they have the common factor $1+i$. Letting $a=2n+1$ we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{a+i}{1+i}&=\frac{2n+1+i}{1+i}=\frac{(2n+1+i)(1-i)}{(1+i)(1-i)}\\
&=\frac{2n+1+1-(2n+1)i+i}2\\
&=(n+1)-ni.
\end{aligned}
$$

**Possibility 2.** When there are no common divisors you should remember to carefully use a smaller remainder at some step. In a division step involving Gaussian integers,
$$a=qb+r,$$
we must make sure that we always have $|r|<|b|$. I find it pedagogically advantageous (though not by any means necessary) to run the extended Euclidean algorithm using augmented matrices. We begin by augmenting an identity matrix with a column of those two numbers (here $a+i$ and $b+i$), and then do elementary row operations, subtracting one row from the other multiplied by "an approximate quotient" $q$. As an example, consider $a=5$, $b=8$, so we want to calculate the modular inverses of $5+i$ and $8+i$ modulo the other:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}1&0&5+i\\0&1&8+i\end{array}\right)
$$
We can first use $q=1$ and write $8+i=1\cdot(5+i)+3$ because $|3|<|5+i|$, so in the first step we subtract the first row from the second
$$
\rightarrow\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}1&0&5+i\\-1&1&3\end{array}\right).
$$
Then we can use $q=2$ as in $5+i=2\cdot3+(-1+i)$ we have $|-1+i|<|3|$. Subtract the second row multiplied by two from the first
$$
\rightarrow\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}3&-2&-1+i\\-1&1&3\end{array}\right).
$$
Next we can use $q=-1-i$ because $(-1-i)(-1+i)=2$ and therefore
$(3+i)=(-1-i)(-1+i)+1.$ Subtract the first row multiplied by $-1-i$ from the second. Or, rather, add the first row multiplied by $1+i$ to the second
$$
\rightarrow\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}3&-2&-1+i\\2+3i&-1-2i&1\end{array}\right).
$$
We got a unit (here $1$) remainder to appear in the augmented column, so we know that
gcd is equal to one (had we gotten another unit, for example $i$, as a remainder instead, we would then multiply the row by the reciprocal). Whenever our augmented matrix has a row $(a\ b\ |\ c)$ we have the relation $a(5+i)+b(8+i)=c$, so from the last row we can read
$$
(2+3i)(5+i)-(1+2i)(8+i)=1
$$
telling us that the inverse of $5+i$ modulo $8+i$ is $(5+i)^{-1}=2+3i$ and that the inverse of $8+i$ modulo $5+i$ is $(8+i)^{-1}=-(1+2i)$.

Of course, you can use representatives of your choice for these cosets. Modulo a Gaussian of the form $a+i$ [we can always use integers modulo $a^2+1$ as representatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/23358/11619). Here
$$
2+3i\equiv 2+3i-3(8+i)=-22\equiv-22+65=43\pmod{8+i}
$$
(I used $65=(8+i)(8-i)$ to get a positive integer remainder), and
$$
-1-2i\equiv-1-2i+2(5+i)=9\pmod{5+i}.
$$

Comment: The last paragraph is actually yet another guess as to what the OP may want. If this is for an application in some program, a remainder (= a coset representative) of some standard form may be preferred even though the modular inverse truly is a **coset modulo the dividend** as opposed to a number.

Comment: Re: **augmented matrix form of the extended Euclidean algorithm**: readers may find it helpful to first learn this method for integers, for which see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) and its links.